# Program crashes when trying to scan a string

Tags: c

I'm having trouble scanning data from a .dat file containing arbitrary game results (for testing the program)

The results are formatted as follows: (# representing the score as an integer)

team_a # team_b #
team_a # team_b #
team_a # team_b #
.
.
.
team_a # team_b #

Each row is a different game.

What I'm trying to do with my code at the moment is to use the fgets() function to scan each game/row, then use the sscanf_s() function to take the data from each row (seeing as though i know the way it is formatted) and store it into the data structure i've defined.

I'm more than happy to take any advice on changes i should make to the way i'm going about getting the data into the struct if there is an easier, faster and/more reliable (foolproof) way to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Plase read [Why is `while(!feof(inp2b))` always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: See my wrong answer there, it's because you don't use a white space after every `,` your code is hard to read because of that. It's hard to see where an identifier ends or where the next one starts, so `game_results[i].first_team_name,&game_results[i].first_team_score` made me think of `game_results[i], first_team_name, &game_results[i].first_team_score` which as you can see would make my answer correct

Comment: I think the problem might be with `sscanf_s`, Microsoft's safe `sscanf`. It expects a buffer size after each string argument, i.e. after arguments for the `%s`, `%c` and `%[` format. See the description and example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t6z7bya3.aspx).

Comment: That's another thing, if you are learning use ANSI C. Specially if you are going to ask here. Many of SO users don't have access to a MSVC compiler like myself, and I can't compile your code to test it.

Comment: As pointed out by M Oehm, your `sscanf_s` looks suspucious, please, read [Things to Avoid in C/C++ -- feof()](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-58.html):  What has happened is the last line of the file was read, but not the EOF. When the loop returns, the `fgets()` attempts to read one more record and failed.

Comment: `data_file_line` can hold 15 lines and `game_results` can hold 128 results yet you use the same index variable, `i` for both. If the loop goes more than 15 loops you have a buffer overflow in `data_file_line`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings such as `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` or `clang -Weverything`.  Some of your mistakes in the above code may be detected by the compiler.

Comment: Trying to take it all on board, thanks for all the comments (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft's secure `sscanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t6z7bya3.aspx) has a slightly different way of interpreting format specifiers and arguments: In order to prevent buffer overflows, each string format (`%s`, `%c` and `%[`) must pass the corresponding buffer size after the buffer.

So your scan command should read:

```
    sscanf_s(data_file_line[i],
        "%s %d %s %d",
        game_results[i].first_team_name,
        sizeof(game_results[i].first_team_name),
        &game_results[i].first_team_score,
        game_results[i].second_team_name,
        sizeof(game_results[i].second_team_name),
        &game_results[i].second_team_score);
```

There are some other issues with your code:

- You should check the return value of `sscanf_s` so you know that the line has been parsed successfully. The return value is the number of items converted, so in your case it should be 4. Also note that `%s` scans words and team names like "Man Utd" and "Stoke City" have two words and will not parse correctly.
- As others have noted, the `feof` construct will make you read the file once too many. Forget about `foef` and use the return values of the reading functions instead. For eample, `fgets` returns `NULL` when the end of the file is reached, so you can use that as loop condition: `while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) ...`
- You don't check whether `i` overflows. If you have a long file, `i` might not be big enough.
- If you are parsing and storing the lines right away, there's no need to have an array of lines; just use one line buffer over and over.

Comment: Ahhhhh kay, i was wondering about what -https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t6z7bya3.aspx- meant by buffer, and how to implement it. I'll fix all that up and see how i go. Also, team names such as Man Utd for example are represented in the data file as 'ManUtd' so that makes life a bit easier. 
 Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

I simplified a little and it works fine. Your work is not finished. Please try this,

```
 #include <usual.h>

 #define MAX_NAME_CHARS 15
 #define MAX_DATA_FILE_LINE_LENGTH 32
 #define MAX_GAME_RESULTS 128

 int main( void )
 {
   FILE *inp2b;

   typedef struct game_results
   {
     char first_team_name[MAX_NAME_CHARS];
     int first_team_score;
     char second_team_name[MAX_NAME_CHARS];
     int second_team_score;
   } game_results_t;

   game_results_t game_results[MAX_GAME_RESULTS];
   char data_file_line[MAX_DATA_FILE_LINE_LENGTH][MAX_DATA_FILE_LINE_LENGTH];
   int errorcode = 0;
   int i = 0;

 //errorcode = fopen_s(&inp2b,"C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\DATAFILES FOR PA2\\input2b.dat","r");
   inp2b = fopen( "C:\\testdat\\input2b.dat", "r" );

   if ( inp2b == NULL )
     errorcode = 1;

   if ( errorcode != 0 )
   {
     printf( "Error opening 2nd data file!\n\n" );
     return ( 0 );
   }
   else
   {
     printf( "\n\n\nFile was opened successfully!\n\n" );
   }

   i = 0;

   while ( !feof( inp2b ) )
   {
     fgets( data_file_line[i], MAX_DATA_FILE_LINE_LENGTH, inp2b );
     puts( data_file_line[i] );
     printf( "\n" );
     //   sscanf_s(data_file_line[i],"%s %d %s %d",game_results[i].first_team_name,&game_results[i].first_team_score,game_results[i].second_team_name,&game_results[i].second_team_score);
     sscanf( data_file_line[i], "%s %d %s %d", game_results[i].first_team_name,
        &game_results[i].first_team_score,
        game_results[i].second_team_name,
        &game_results[i].second_team_score );

     printf( "\n\n %s %d %s %d \n\n", game_results[i].first_team_name,
        game_results[i].first_team_score,
        game_results[i].second_team_name,
        game_results[i].second_team_score );
     i++;
   }

   fclose( inp2b );

   return ( 0 );
 }
```

Comment: `while(!feof(inp2b))` is still the wrong logic for parsing a file, since you do no check the return value of `fgets`, whatever you do after that uses indetermined data.

Comment: You are right, I said : the program now runs but you still have work to do, I am trying to overcome the first problem first : the crash. Cheers.

Comment: Using the changes made in this answer and the above answer to get it working. Thanks mate